# Python: Beautiful soup to get text

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, lxml

I'm trying to get link under `a href` and also the text available in the next `<td scope = "raw">`

I've tried

```
url = "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1491829/0001171520-19-000171-index.htm"
records = []
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    Name = link.text
    Links = link.get('href')
    records.append((Name, Links))
```

However this gives me `eps8453.htm` as text since this is the text under tag `<a href>`. Is there any way we can look for the text i.e. "10-K" in the tag `<td scope = "raw">` next to tag `<a href>`

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Use find_next `<td>` tag after `<a>` tag inside table.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1491829/0001171520-19-000171-index.htm"
html=requests.get(url).text
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
records = []
for link in soup.find('table', class_='tableFile').find_all('a'):
    Name = link.text

    Links = link.get('href')
    text=link.find_next('td').contents[0]
    print(Name,text)
    records.append((Name, Links,text))
```

Output:

```
eps8453.htm 10-K
ex31-1.htm EX-31.1
ex31-2.htm EX-31.2
ex32-1.htm EX-32.1
yu-logo.jpg GRAPHIC
yu_sig.jpg GRAPHIC
0001171520-19-000171.txt
```